# jQuery and passing variables from decision structure

Tags: jquery, function

I'm using jQuery and I'm having an issue with passing a variable to a function from the value of a checkbox.  I can pass to the function from a Switch statement, but not from an If Then.  I'm just looking for some assistance as to why.

```
 $("input[type=checkbox]").change( function() {

if($(this).is(":checked")){
    passVar = ( $(this).val() );
    addToOrder(passVar);
    alert(passVar);
} else {
    alert("off");
}  });
```

Any assistance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting an error with the above code?

Comment: That code looks good, check http://jsfiddle.net/qg8bM/

Comment: I'm not getting an error, but it's not calling the function or passing the variable although the alert works just fine.

Comment: If the alert works and you don't see any errors in console, then the problem is inside your function, can you show us the code?

Comment: `   function addToOrder(t)
    {
    tempString = t.split(",");
    Receipttext = Receipttext + "<br>" + tempString[0] + " - " + tempString[1];
    //alert(t);
    }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its Working Fine. See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jpnathanstock/yGvmh/1/)

```
$("input[type=checkbox]").change( function() {

if($(this).is(":checked")){
    passVar = ( $(this).val() );
    alert(passVar);
    addToOrder(passVar);
} else {
    alert("off");
}  });

function addToOrder(t) {
    alert(t);
    tempString = t.split(","); 
    Receipttext = Receipttext + "<br>" + tempString[0] + " - " + tempString[1]; //alert(t);
}
```

Comment: @Bob Randolph i can update my answer in fiddle check it.http://jsfiddle.net/jpnathanstock/yGvmh/3/